# Ref/Out on 2D Array with Ironpython

Tags: c#, clr, ironpython

I have a python script that needs to do some communication with a C# function. The function expects three parameters, two of which are returned via the `out` keyword. The declaration looks something like this:

```
RunComputation(InfoParams locInfo, out double[,] dataTable, out int numPoints){ ... }
```

Since Python is a dynamically typed language, it doesn't know how to deal with the **out** keywords. I did some searching and found some stuff about clr.StrongBox and clr.Reference, which seem fairly simple to use in situations where you need to pass a strongly typed object.

For the numPoints parameter, I can define something like this in the python code:

```
 num_points = clr.Reference[int]
```

And it seems to be fine. The problem comes from the **dataTable** array. I don't know the syntax to tell it that my strongly typed object is an array of doubles. The error it gives informs me that it's expecting an instance of Type `StrongBox[Array[float]]`. I tried import Array from System to see if I could add that C# type in as a reference, but it failed. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know much about IronPython programming, but perhaps you can consider adding a C# wrapper function that takes your single InfoParams parameter and returns an object composing of both the `double[,] dataTable` and `int numPoints`.  That way C# handles the outs and IronPython just gets an object from which it can access that data via its two exposed properties.

Comment: Makes sense. I'll give that a go while I wait to see if someone has a direct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using only `out` arguments you can also use the [implicit way](http://ironpython.net/documentation/dotnet/dotnet.html#id52), i.e. if you don't pass any `out` argument to the method, they're returned as a tuple.

e.g.

```
d = Dictionary[str, float]()
(keyfound,value) = d.TryGetValue("b")
```

It works also with `ref` arguments.
Imagine to have the following method:

```
int Foo(int x, double[,] v)
```

you can call the method in this way:

```
nrows = 5
ncols = 5
array = Array.CreateInstance(float, nrows, ncols)
(x, arrayNew) = obj.Foo(3, array)
```

and finally, the modified value of `array` is contained into `arrayNew`